# failure in converting type from string to long in spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table filled with data from database, now I'm working on a method that deletes a row by giving its id:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/appel/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id ) {
    appelService.deleteAppel(id);
    return  ("index");
}
```

the thymeleaf table is this:

```html
<tbody>
<tr th:each="appel : ${list}">
    <td th:text="${appel.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${appel.serviceCode}"></td>
    <td th:text="${appel.description}"></td>
    <td th:text="${appel.answer}"></td>
    <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
    <td><a th:href="@{'/appel/delete/' + appel.id}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Every time I click on the delete link I get this message:

[image: error page]

I don't understand where the error is and what could I change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems to be a problem with the string concatenation in the`th:href`, try with something like this instead.

```
<td><a th:href="@{/appel/delete/{id}(id=${appel.id})}" >Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: thank you it works now i really appreciate your help